# How many blood points can a ghoul use within a turn?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I have recently started running a ghoul campaign however no matter how hard I look I can't find how many blood points a ghoul can use a turn. I know that vampires are limited by their generation with lower generation vampires being able to use more blood points in a turn.

As such my question is how many vitae points can a ghoul use within a round?

Note: I am using the V20 core book and fatal addiction addition book.

Comment: By "Anniversary Edition", do you mean Vampire: The Masquerade 20th Anniversary Edition (also known as V20)?

Comment: Edited the question. Thank you for pointing that up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One Point Per Turn

The V20 rule on this can be found on page 400 of the V20 Dark Ages rulebook.

“Regardless of the domitor’s generation, ghouls can retain a maximum of 10 blood points and spend one per turn. The blood pool cap increases by one every century, while the rate of consumption remains the same.”

Answer (score 6):

## Assume One

Generally, Ghouls are treated in all ways as on the bottom rung of the ladder of special abilities compared to vampires (e.g. barely getting the first point of Disciplines), so it's safe to assume that they can't spend more than a high-gen vampire. That is, one point at a time.

Comment: While that was what I was assuming I was hoping for some quote from a book or something similar. As such I'll opt to wait for a day in total before accepting your answer.

Comment: Also notable: ghouls are likely to have access to very few points of *vitae* for any purpose at a given time, and they may need that volume of fluid to remain alive and functional. If aging has been suppressed due to ghouling for very long, it's even more critical that they not use all of it.

Comment: Ghouls can safely store a total of 12 vitae with a medicine check. (Replacing their human blood via transfusion. )